# Repository method only works returning the whole entity instead of some properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I cannot return specific properties of an entity class from a repository method.

> Exception stacktrace

```
Resolving exception from handler 
[public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object>            
org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch
(
org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,
org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>, 
java.lang.String,

org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,
org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.Persis
tentEntityResourceAssembler
)
]
 : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!
```

> **Entity** class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="reference_data")
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name="MyTable.findX", query = "SELECT t.name FROM MyTable t WHERE t.catId = 330 ")
})
public class MyTable implements Serializable { 
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="cat_id")
  private Long catId;

  @Column(name="name")
  private String name;
}
```

> **Repository** interface

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "myTables", path = "myTables")
//public interface MyTableDataRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyTable, Long> {  // This didn't work.
public interface MyTableDataRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTable, Long> {
  //@Query("SELECT a.name FROM MyTable a WHERE a.catId = 330 ") -- This didn't work.
  //@Query(value= "SELECT r.name FROM my_table r ", nativeQuery = true) -- This didn't work either.
  @Query("SELECT DISTINCT a.name FROM MyTable a WHERE a.catId = 330 ") // This didn't work either.
  List<String> findX();  // This didn't work.

  //List<MyDTO> findX(); // DTO with one property: String name.. didn't work either.
}
```

As you can see, none of the repository methods above works even though they should according to thousands of examples.

The only way I have got it working is as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM MyTable a WHERE a.catId = 330") // This WORKS
List<MyTable> findX();  // This WORKS
```

> Technical stack

```
+-------------------------------+-----------------+
| Dependency                    | Version         |
+-------------------------------+-----------------+
| spring-boot-starter-web       | 1.3.5.RELEASE   |
| spring-boot-starter-data-jpa  | 1.3.5.RELEASE   |
| spring-boot-starter-data-rest | 1.3.5.RELEASE   |
| HikariCP                      | 2.4.6           |
| postgresql                    | 9.3-1102-jdbc41 |
| JDK                           | 8               |
+-------------------------------+-----------------+
```

I'd really appreciate any help in getting the query to return only selected properties to work.

Comment: What you are running into is how Spring Data REST has been designed. It works only with entities. See @Will's answer below for more details and the way to work around the design constraint.

Answer (score 4):

This stems from a misunderstanding of what Spring Data REST can do. Whilst you can do what you are describing through direct repository access, you are accessing this method through the automatically exposed REST endpoint, and these only work on mapped classes. This means that any repository methods you expose with Spring Data REST need to return entity types, i.e. those which are annotated with `@Entity` which `java.lang.String` is not.

Whilst you *could* create a String class wrapper that is also a database entity, [as is suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969682/how-does-one-create-a-custom-query-in-jparepository-but-return-an-object-other-t) this is a terrible approach, and totally unnecessary.

The proper way to achieve what you want is to use projections. You would define a projection interface exposing the fields you want like so:

```
@Projection(name = "myTableNameProjection", types = MyTable.class)
public interface MyTableNameProjection {
    String getName();
}
```

And then, when you make the request, specify that it is the *projection* you are interested in.

`curl 'http://localhost:8080/mytables?projection=myTableNameProjection'`

The results returned will be projections only including the names of the entities. This works equally on individual requests (e.g. `/mytables/1`) or repository search methods.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362756/how-do-i-apply-a-projection-to-a-spring-data-rest-query-method-resource) is a related question explaining projections, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) is the relevant section of the documentation, and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/projections) is an example project.

Comment: Your explanation is only partially correct. Spring Data JPA is perfectly capable of returning `List<String>` or `List<Integer>` or anything equivalent. However, Spring Data REST only works with default view of data, which is entities. The documentation and example you have referenced are also Spring Data REST related.

Comment: @manish Yes, I assumed that the question was in relation to spring data REST, as it is tagged as such and it's the only situation where I have seen this error before. I'll update the answer to reflect that this is a spring data REST specific quirk.

Comment: folks, I know the SpringDataRest works on entities only, but this has a disadvantage when you want to avoid exposing confidential information, otherwise would a view database object work to expose the confidential table-fields?

Comment: @Jrr If you never want the confidential fields to be exposed, mark them with `@JsonIgnore`, they wont be serialized. Alternatively, you can define a default entity projection for a repository called an 'excerpt' projection, which doesn't expose the confidential fields. You can then set this in `@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection=MyProjection.class)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the return value should not be `List<String>` but `List<Object[]>`.

Answer (score 0):

folks, I have tried with a lot of possible work-arounds (tkxs for your inputs), but under spring-data-rest just the whole entity works otherwise I get: 'cause": null message: PersistentEntity must not be null!' .. this needs to be written in some place.. just to avoid a headache you know.
Also, according to spring-data-* documentation we can use @RestResource(exported = false) to hide query methods and entities' fields in HAL..   cuNextChallenge.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.I fixed it by adding @Service annotation in my services file