# How to specify which fields to return with @query anotation in Spring Data?

Tags: spring-data-rest

When I run the following query using the @query anotation in Spring Boot, it returns the correct result:

```
SELECT p FROM Collection p WHERE LOWER(p.description) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%',:searchTerm, '%'))

{
    "_embedded": {
        "collections": [
            {
                "place": "Blessington",
                "description": "Collection of old shoes for recycling",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/collections/1"
                    },
                    "collection": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/collections/1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/collections/search/findByDescription?searchTerm=shoe"
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to specify the fields to return:

```
SELECT p.description FROM Collection p WHERE LOWER(p.description) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%',:searchTerm, '%'))
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "cause": null,
    "message": "PersistentEntity must not be null!"
}
```

**How do I specify which fields to return with @query annotation in Spring Data?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repository method only works returning the whole entity instead of some properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007162/repository-method-only-works-returning-the-whole-entity-instead-of-some-properti)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested link does not fully cover all possibilities.

From the Hopper release of Spring Data it is possible to directly return Projections directly from Query methods:

https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/03/what-s-new-in-spring-data-hopper#projections-on-repository-query-methods

So you can therefore do:

```
public interface ThingRepository extends JpaRepository<Thing, Long>{

   @Query("select t from Thing t .....")
   public List<ThingProjection> findBySomeCriteria(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it seems the question that Manish posted the link to has the answer.

Answer: You can't.

Spring data will return the whole entity, not individual fields.  You can't make it do that.  If you want to do that you have to use *projections*. See linked post.

Thanks @Manish